# How to downgrade/unpatch bash for ubuntu 12.04 LTS to get back to the original vulnerable version of it?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried resolving the the shell-shock vulnerability of environment variables by updating bash. Is there any way to downgrade the bash and again try and demonstrate for the shell-shock vulnerability?

Comment: Not safely, so I would not attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick from all published versions in 12.04 from here, bottom of page under Releases. Opening the individual version pages will present the changelog, pick the version just before the changes you don't want.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/bash

Click on your arch in the Builds section & download the .deb, then use dpkg to install it, ie.

sudo dpkg -i /path/to/downloaded deb.

Ex. -

sudo dpkg -i /home/doug/Downloads/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb